# Voltage regulating

Tags: voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit

My first post here, please keep in mind that I hardly know anything about electrical engineering so please keep any replies in layman terms, thank you!

I bought this [30cm white LED strip](http://www.ebay.com/itm/181489001476?_trksid=p2059210.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT).

It's set up to run from 12 volts. The thing is I would like to use it at 6 volts. I can see that there are soldered IC chips on it: an M7 chip and a 78L05 chip; from what I could find out the 78L05 chip is a voltage regulator.

What would be the simplest way to get this to run from 6V?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps post a picture of the circuit (pcb).  (Both sides if there are copper traces or components on both sides.)

Comment: Here's a image, the 78L05 is second chip from the left https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Zjegs8UFKRcEJaMFdjRnhmVzg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: It's not going to happen. The 78L05's dropout voltage is in no case low enought to run from 6V.

Comment: What would be the simplest way to have the the item run on 6v instead of 12v?

Comment: OK, hard to tell what's going on.  (What's the part number on the other IC?)  If you have access to a bench power supply you could try running it from a lower voltage and see what happens.  It may be that the LM7805 just sets the voltage for that other IC in the picture.  As Matt points out above, it will take at least ~6.5V to turn on the lm7805

Comment: What I'm looking to achive is something similar to this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzaf1gy0vMw
But using the above led strip I linked to earlier.

Answer (score 1):

To save the hassle of trying to modify a device to take a different voltage, I would personally consider using a "step-up" or a boost DC-to-DC converter to simply provide the required voltage.

One like [this boost converter](http://www.ebay.com/itm/DC-DC-Adjustable-Step-up-boost-Power-Converter-Module-XL6009-Replace-LM2577-/371054648639?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item5664949d3f) from eBay would be able to take in 6 volts and supply 12 volts on its output.

Your eBay listing did not provide amperage/power requirements, but the ~10 watts this provides should be enough

Comment: The module from the link is boost converter, buck would not help here.

Comment: @venny: Whoops, thankyou for correcting that

Comment: I was just on my way out to buy one of those, luckily I checked here first. Please keep the suggestions coming. :)

Comment: would this work?
http://www.ebay.com/itm/LM2596S-DC-DC-Step-Down-Adjust-Power-Supply-Module-new-/251647976386?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3a976363c2

Comment: Wait a minute... isn't a boost converter what I need here? The leds currently need 12v to run, I only want to feed them from a 6v source, adding a boost converter would let me do just that, correct?

Answer (score 0):

The M7 and 78L05 form a 5V power supply. If your 6V is well regulated you could try putting a diode from input to output of the 78L05, shunting it out of the circuit.

That will reduce the 6V input to a bit less than 5V. However if your 6V supply is 'dirty', badly regulated etc. (**or** if I miss-guessed the schematic) you could burn out the microcontroller and your gadget will be trash.

If you're prepared to take that risk, you can give it a try.

Edit: This is for 6VDC- the OP has revised to 6VAC so this is not useful answer, see comment below.

[image]

If you plug it into anything more than about 6.5V (including the 12V it was originally designed for) it could be destroyed- would definitely be destroyed at 12V.

Comment: I might give that a try, I have two backups if anything would go wrong. I bought a boost DC to DC converter and I got no reading at all from the out put on it. I think however I forgot to mention a crucial part, the 6v power source I'm tapping in to is AC, (a pinball machine) Yes, I know I'm a n00b!

Comment: If you feed it 6VAC it will not work properly and will likely die! Instead of the diode try adding a 1000uF/16V (2200uF would be better) from pin 3 (+ lead) to pin 2 (- lead). Do **not** put the diode on there.

Comment: Okay, I see, thank you! Now it's just a matter of finding somewhere to buy that cap.

Comment: I installed a 2200uF today and it works just like you said, having said that it was pretty hard to solder the cap to the lm7805. Is there any other point where I could solder the cap too?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with extending the capacitor leads with thin wire for an inch or two.

Comment: Okay, but it have to be in that exact spot? I think it was kinda har to solder ther due to the small solder points. What would happen if I soldered the cap to the black and red wire that connects to the strip?

Comment: The ones marked for DC that have 6VAC on them? That would make the capacitor swell up and potentially explode, but more likely just vent its smelly electrolyte. It might work if you added another diode such as a 1N5817 externally, plus the capacitor, but you're running out of headroom on the regulator.